# IIS Web Serive Idle Timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know that this is a common issue and has been discussed here long time ago and some solutions are suggested. However, none of them really solve my problem.

I have Windows Server R2 with IIS 7.5 installed. There were over 40 web services hosted in the same application pool. The problem is some web services will go idle after some time, due to those web services are less active. The web services have to be always ready since they are used to handle phone banking transactions. When those web services being called after idling, they take longer time to respond and hence hit the timeout. Customer will experience the transaction performed is unable to process on the phone.

There is an interim solution for this problem, which is a small application was developed and implemented to send dummy request to each web services twice a day, in order to wake up the web services. However, this cannot be done too frequently as this will affect the bank's reporting.

The settings below are set for the application pool:

```
startMode = AlwaysRunning, idleTimeout = 00:00:00, 
preloadEnabled = true
```

Is there any other way instead of the settings above to overcome such problem? Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is not to add those dummy requests to the reports. Log them in a technical log, but don't expose them to the client.